# joining the medians of boxes with a line in a boxplot chart in TIBCO spotfire?

Tags: ironpython, spotfire, tibco

How to join the medians of boxes with a line in a boxplot chart in TIBCO spotfire can be done either using ironpython script or without..

Comment: Can you add a graphic showing what you want?

Comment: http://blogs.sas.com/content/graphicallyspeaking/2015/12/04/boxplot-with-connect/#prettyPhoto/0/

Answer (score 2):

For this, the lines are Mean and Median. The line doesn't simply "connect them" though this graphic should have a straight line and not one that looks like a combination chart. The only combo chart that would work similarly to this is the Line / Bar combo chart. However, you can insert a line for the Mean and Median.

```
Right Click on your Chart > Properties > Lines & Curves
```

Then insert a mean and/or median line

Comment: Right Click on your Chart > Properties > Lines & Curves, using this you get individual lines of each median  of the boxes

Comment: What I really wanted was to connect the median points of the boxes.